# Can I get the source code of Smart Contart by it's Abi and deployed Address?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I deployed the smart contract on the polygon testnet blockchain

Answer (score 0):

If your contract is verified, you can view the source code directly. But I don't think that's the case.

-- In most cases, the answer is NO.

However, you may be able to find the source code when there is another smart contract had the same byte codes as yours.

[image]